# Javascript redirect function is not redirecting

Tags: javascript, html

```
function myFunction() {
  location.replace("https://www.w3schools.com")
}
```

in the script tag

```
  <button onclick='myFunction()'>Submit</button>
```

in the html

Any idea why this very basic command doesn't work?

Comment: If the button is in a form, add `type="button"` so it doesn't submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

check this example:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_redirect_webpage

If your button is inside the form then need to specify as type of button

```html
<form>
 <button onclick="myFunction()" type="button">Replace document</button>
</form
```

Answer (score -1):

I tested your code and it works fine..
Try clearing your cache inspect and right click on reload choose clear cache.

Did u link your script file ?

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```